# How to get the BUILD_USER_EMAIL in Jenkins when job triggered by email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How to get the BUILD_USER_EMAIL in Jenkins when job triggered by email

I ma using Jenkins version 2.204.1 (latest version)

I have used User Build vars plugin and enabled "Set jenkins user build variables" option

In Execute  Shell command written

echo "Email id:$BUILD_USER_EMAIL"

exit 0

Where /How to get the variable as Email id from which build got triggered

Comment: What is the result of your echo?

Comment: eclipse-workspace] $ sh -xe C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins9038205307519043265.sh
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified